# Throwing time out expired exception while executing Query from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am having a **table with 1000000** values.
From that I need to retrieve some values which are fulfilling my conditions.
But when I executing the below mentioned query from ASP.NET it throws an **TimeOut expired** Exception. 
How to avoid this one

```
"SELECT ID,Intime,OutTime from [dbo].MasterLog 
WHERE CardId=(SELECT ID from User WHERE Name like 'ki%')"
```

It will be very useful if I got the answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add an index to the column in the where clause of your query.

[check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx)

[this also](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/)

- And also think about **Stored Procedures**
- Coz stored procedures will help a lot to retrieve data in a short
  time from DB.
- Always avoid writing query in front end.

But first and most important thing is indexing, If you having more data means index it.

Answer (score 2):

Besides update your connection and command timeout, if you add a non-cluster index on CardID and include column ID, Intime, OutTime, which is a covering index, your query will be faster, that will help.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NCI_MasterLog_CardID] ON [dbo].[MasterLog]
(
    [CardID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ID],
            [InTime],
            [OutTime[) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `WEB.CONFIG TIMEOUT` option is long time
2. IIS Application Pool `TIMEOUT` option is long time
3. (Current Page) `Request Header KeepAlive = true` setting

Answer (score 0):

Try these,

1. Specify SQL Connection Timeout and Command Timeout properly.
2. Add index to the table on CardId
3. Selecting TOP 100 / 1000 records first and try to get the rest as and when required to improve the performance of the query